# pandas парсинг по 2м столбцам одновременно

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Есть файл csv типа:

```
frame.number,frame.time_epoch,frame.interface_name,udp.port
1,1557138027.796,lo,8000
2,1557138027.796,lo2,7788
3,1557138027.797,lo,8000
4,1557138027.797,lo2,7788
5,1557138027.798,lo,7788
6,1557138027.798,lo2,8000
7,1557138027.799,lo,8000
8,1557138027.799,lo,7788
9,1557138027.8,lo,8000
10,1557138027.8,lo,7788
11,1557138027.801,lo2,8000
12,1557138027.801,lo,7788
13,1557138027.802,lo,8000
14,1557138027.802,lo,7788
15,1557138027.803,lo,8000
16,1557138027.803,lo,7788
17,1557138027.804,lo2,7788
18,1557138027.804,lo2,8000
19,1557138027.805,lo,7788
```

Нужно нарисовать график, которые будет парсить так:
1)брать только lo и делить маркеры по портам 8000 и 7788
2)брать только lo2 и делать маркеры по портам 8000 и 7788 
рисовать 2 разных графика.

пробую так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Plot():
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', nrows=100)
    lo = df.loc[df['udp.port'].isin(['8000'])]
    lo2 = df.loc[df['udp.port'].isin(['7788'])]
    x = lo['frame.number']
    y = lo['frame.time_epoch']
    x1 = lo2['frame.number']
    y1 = lo2['frame.time_epoch']
    plt.figure(3)
    plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', label='8000')
    plt.scatter(x1,y1, marker='o', label='7788')
    plt.xlabel('Number of packets')
    plt.ylabel('Arriving time (in seconds)')
    plt.title('title')
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('Graph3.png')
    print('Graph3.png -> OK')
```

на выходе получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но оно парсит и рисует только порты 8000 и 7788 для lo / lo2 
Как рисовать только lo -> 8000 + 7788 и lo2 - > 8000 + 7788?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, хотя бы часть входных данных в электронном виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сначала сгруппировать датафрейм по столбцам **'frame.interface_name'** и **'udp.port'** и потом рисовать график для каждой группы.

#### 1. Всё на одном графике

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'red', 'green']

# Группируем датафрейм и рисуем график для каждой группы
for name, group in df.groupby(['frame.interface_name', 'udp.port']):
    label = '_'.join([str(n) for n in name])

    group.plot.scatter(x='frame.number', y='frame.time_epoch',
                       ax=ax, 
                       label=label,
                       c=colors.pop())

ax.set(xlabel='Number of packets', ylabel='Arriving time (in seconds)')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### 2. Отдельный график для каждого интерфейса

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12,8))
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'red', 'green']

for name, group in df.groupby(['frame.interface_name', 'udp.port']):
    label = '_'.join([str(n) for n in name])

    group.plot.scatter(x='frame.number', y='frame.time_epoch',
                       ax=ax[0] if name[0]=='lo' else ax[1], 
                       label=label,
                       c=colors.pop())

for x in ax:
    x.set(xlabel='Number of packets', ylabel='Arriving time (in seconds)')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы неверно делаете выборку из дейтафрейма. Я бы сделал так:

```
df.set_index("frame.number", inplace=True)
df["frame.time_epoch"] = df["frame.time_epoch"].astype("float")

x = df.index
y1 = df['frame.time_epoch'].where(df['frame.interface_name'] == 'lo')
y2 = df['frame.time_epoch'].where(df['frame.interface_name'] == 'lo2')

plt.scatter(x,y1)
plt.scatter(x,y2, c='r')
plt.legend()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметьте, что я не менял легенду, чтобы было видно, что на графике именно время. для каждого интерфейса.